# Is there a way to restrict direct write access to the database in Microsoft Access 2007?

Tags: permissions, sql-server, microsoft-access-2007

I'd like to set up an Access (2007) project that contains queries on a database (actually in MS SQL Server 2005), but I don't want to allow any direct writing to the database.

How can I make it read-only?

Comment: ADP or MDB/ACCDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an Access question, but a SQL Server question. Set up roles in your SQL Server and tie them to the appropriate user groups and your users will inherit the appropriate permissions on the data according to their group membership.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the tables and create queries with read-only property to true.

Answer (score -2):

MS-SQL-Server Queries are represented in Acces as read-only tables when linked with ODBC. The lack of a primary key does the job.

Comment: This is not true as stated. Views can be read/write, but it depends entirely on what's in the view. And, as you say, if there's no PK it causes problems. I also recommend a timestamp field in all SQL Server tables and in all views.

Comment: The Question was: How to manage to get a read-only View. My Answer is short, direct and correct. 
You didn't specify what sort of problems may arise - so please?

Comment: I don't know why I should be answering a further question. I'd have to do research to find the answer. Surely it's as simple as setting the SQL Server permissions on the View, but your answer here IS FALSE. It is not the case that a SQL Server View is "repesented in Access as read-only." That statement is just COMPLETELY WRONG as it stands (hence the downvote).